# derivitive of partial normal distribition wrt mean

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution

For a random variable of $ x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})\,$, how we can compute the **derivative** of expected value of $f$ w.r.t $\mu$?

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    x, & \text{if $a<x<b$}.\\
    g(x), & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I want to minimize the $E[f(x)]$ by finding the optimal $\mu$, so I need to set the derivative of $E[f(x)]$ w.r.t $\mu$ to zero and solve the equation. I have the derivative of $E[g(x)]$. so I just need to find the derivative of $E[x]$ w.r.t $\mu$ for $a<x<b$. is there any easy equation/approximation for that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: added more details